# Issue with Router, Redirect and authentication context in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router, react-hooks

I am still new to React hooks, and I am trying to adapt [some code](https://medium.com/@johnwcassidy/firebase-authentication-hooks-and-context-d0e47395f402) to only allow access to some routes if the user is authenticated in Firebase. And at the same time, I want the user to be redirected to home if he types a path that does not exist. And if he is trying to access one of the protected routes while being logged out, he should also be redirected to home. Here is what my App.js looks like:

```
import React, {Fragment, lazy, Suspense, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {CssBaseline, MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core";
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import theme from "./theme";
import GlobalStyles from "./GlobalStyles";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Pace from "./shared/components/Pace";
import Firebase from "./firebase";
import FirebaseContext from "./firebase-context";

const firebase = new Firebase();

const LoggedInComponent = lazy(() => import("./logged_in/components/Main"));

const LoggedOutComponent = lazy(() => import("./logged_out/components/Main"));

function onAuthStateChange(callback) {
    return firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {
            callback({loggedIn: true});
        } else {
            callback({loggedIn: false});
        }
    });
}

function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({loggedIn: false});

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange(setUser);
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    }, [setUser]);
    console.log("logged in?", user.loggedIn);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <CssBaseline/>
                    <GlobalStyles/>
                    <Pace color={theme.palette.primary.light}/>
                    <Suspense fallback={<Fragment/>}>
                        <Switch>
                            {user.loggedIn && <Route path="/c" component={LoggedInComponent}/>}
                            <Route exact path="/" component={LoggedOutComponent}/>
                            <Redirect to="/"/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Suspense>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </FirebaseContext.Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

serviceWorker.register();

export default App;
```

The problem I have is that when I am logged in and I am on the home page. If I try to add "/c" to the URL to get to the protected part, I get redirected back to the home page, as if I was not logged in.

When I reload the home page while I'm logged in, I get 2 console logs, one that says I'm not logged in and once that says I am. And I think what is happening is that I get redirected before the App has a chance to render and see that I am logged in. Which seems to be confirmed by the fact that, if I comment out my Redirect, I can get to `/c`. But then I don't get the other benefits of that Redirect.

What I have trouble understanding is why `user.loggedIn` is false the first time the component is rendered.

Comment: "What I have trouble understanding is why user.loggedIn is false the first time the component is rendered." - because you set it to false in useState() as intial value

Comment: OK, I get it. But of course, if I set the initial state loggedIn to true, and I try to load the protected route while logged out, it is allowed for a brief moment before the redirection to home kicks in, so it seems risky. What's the solution there?

Comment: You can initialize to null. so now you know if it is null, then still network request is going on so you can load spinner or something. then you can change state using the data you got from backend

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it without reinventing the wheel (and without using ReactFire that depends on crazy experimental React stuff) by using [this third party library](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks). Here is the resulting code:

```
import React, { Fragment, Suspense, lazy, useContext } from "react";
import { MuiThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import theme from "./theme";
import GlobalStyles from "./GlobalStyles";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Pace from "./shared/components/Pace";
import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import FirebaseContext from "./firebase-context";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

const LoggedInComponent = lazy(() => import("./logged_in/components/Main"));

const LoggedOutComponent = lazy(() => import("./logged_out/components/Main"));

function App() {
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  const [user, initialising, error] = useAuthState(firebase.auth);
  console.log("user", user);
  console.log("initialising", initialising);
  console.log("error", error);
  return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Pace color={theme.palette.primary.light} />
        {initialising ? <LinearProgress/> :
        <Suspense fallback={<Fragment />}>
          <Switch>
            {user && <Route path="/c">
              <LoggedInComponent />
            </Route>}
            <Route exact path="/">
              <LoggedOutComponent />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/"/>
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>}
      </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

serviceWorker.register();

export default App;
```

And indeed, I have to delay the display of the routing switch until Firebase auth's hook has finished initialising.